# getting sessions via prefix/wildcards

Tags: regex, wildcard, prefix

I have a tricky question. lets say if we start naming session as :

> $_SESSION['user-msg'], $_SESSION['user-err'], $_SESSION['user-name'],
>   $_SESSION['admin-msg'], $_SESSION['admin-err'],
>   $_SESSION['admin-username']

what if i just want to destroy session those are having key as "user-" only? how we do that?

actually i want to log out admin (backend) only. while the same person is logged in as user on my front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$prefix='user-';
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val)
   if (substr($key, 0, strlen($prefix)) === $prefix)
       unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

I don't think there exists any better option.